# Type error on response of Promise.allSettled()

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I've been trying to use Promise.allSettled on NodeJS with Typescript recently, and I'm facing issues with the response. the allSettled method returns an array with `status: "rejected" | "fulfilled"` and a value, in case it's fulfilled. The problem is, when I try to access the value of the response, I get the following errors:

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'PromiseSettledResult<unknown>'.
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'PromiseRejectedResult'.ts(2339)
```

Below I'll leave a simple example so you can copy the code and try yourself:

```
const p1 = Promise.resolve(50); 
const p2 = Promise.resolve(100); 

const promiseArray = [p1, p2]; 
  
Promise.allSettled( promiseArray ). 
  then( results => results.forEach( result =>  
    console.log(result.status, result.value)));
```

If I run this code on my project, I get an error because of `result.value` at the end.

I'm running my node on version 12.18.3 on Windows, and I've set my target on the `tsconfig.json` as `ES2020` to be able to use the method itself.

Comment: You only have a value attribute where the status is fulfilled, and you're not checking for that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe OMG I can't believe I've spent 3 hours breaking my brain and now you tell me it is this simple. It's solved now, I can't believe it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Still, the TS error seems wrong - `PromiseRejectedResult` should not have `value` but `PromiseSettledResult` should?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

@jonrsharpe answered it:
You only have a value attribute where the status is fulfilled, and you're not checking for that.

So using my own example, it can be fixed as the following:

```
const p1 = Promise.resolve(50); 
const p2 = Promise.resolve(100); 

const promiseArray = [p1, p2]; 
  
Promise.allSettled( promiseArray ). 
  then( results => results.forEach( result =>  
    console.log(result.status,
                result.status === 'fulfilled' && result.value
    );
  ));
```

It now verifies if the promise was fulfilled and then prints the value, if it's the case.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you show how to apply that information to produce working code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Alright. I'm sorry, it's my very fisrt question here and I started learning coding 3 months from now only. I appreciate your time!

Comment: No problem, thanks for improving it - note there's guidance at [answer].

Answer (score 28):

Got same error in case of filter promises array:

```
const promises = ids.map((id) => <some BE API call>);
const resolvedPromises = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
resolvedPromises.filter(({ status }) => status === 'fulfilled').map((p) => p.value);
```

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MntQD.png)

The problem is `allSettled` returns `PromiseSettledResult`, which is not exported at all (I use lib.es2020.promise in `tsconfig`):

```
interface PromiseFulfilledResult<T> {
    status: "fulfilled";
    value: T;
}

interface PromiseRejectedResult {
    status: "rejected";
    reason: any;
}

type PromiseSettledResult<T> = PromiseFulfilledResult<T> | PromiseRejectedResult;
```

and `.map` doesn't understand that all `rejected` promises were filtered in `filtered` method.

So, I even can't import types and cast values to them.

As a temporary solution I suppressed ESLint and TSC rules with comments:

```
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
  // @ts-ignore
```

Then I created same to `PromiseFulfilledResult` interface in the project and used types casting:

```
resolvedPromises.filter(({ status }) => status === 'fulfilled').map((p) => (p as PromiseFulfilledResult).value);
```

As a result I got rid of on error and ESLint/TS rules ignoring comments.

Comment: I ran into the same problem and this was very helpful! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

You can avoid this error if you make a type statement after calling the `allSettled` method. For example, you can immediately enter a type for typescript as follows:

```
const promises = await Promise.allSettled([
  fetch(url).then((response) => response.json()),
  fetch(url).then((response) => response.json()),
]) as {status: 'fulfilled' | 'rejected', value: SomeType}[];
```

After that it will work correctly:

```
const resolvedPromises = promises.filter(({ status }) => status === 'fulfilled');
const responses = resolvedPromises.map((promise) => promise.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just type cast the result of `Promise.allSettled`, for instance:

```js
const [
      someData,
      otherData
    ] = (await Promise.allSettled([
      this.someRepository.count(),
      this.otherRepository.count(),
    ])) as PromiseFulfilledResult<number>[];

 // will verify the promises, but ts doesn't get it
 this.verify(someData, otherData)

 console.log(otherData.value) // ts is okay
```

Number is the type returned from the promise, if you want to type promises with different typings, you could also use `[PromiseFulfilledResult<number>, PromiseFulfilledResult<string>]`